# Image source not readable when watermark used in laravel

Tags: laravel, watermark

I use [this package](https://medium.com/@masoudjahromi/easy-way-to-add-watermark-on-images-in-laravel-3fae44eae49a) for make watermark in laravel . it work in my local but on server I have this error

`**Image source not readable**`

tanks

[image]

Comment: Did you check permissions on the image file?

Comment: yes. it is 0777